# Filtering out the data for Extended Trading Hours in C#

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

I am getting the data from a stock provider that includes the data for Extended Trading Hours.
The data is aggregated 1-minute data points that I convert from JSON to `List<Aggregate>` where aggregate contains High, Low, Open, Close, and Time of the start of the aggregated 1-min window.
My queries encompass multiple trading days - could be hundreds and could be thousands. And my calculation of indicators must exclude after-hours data.
So I have a list of hundreds of items of the object:

```cs
public class Aggregate
{
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public decimal UnixTimestamp { get; set; } // milliseconds
    ...
}
```

and also the `DateTime FromDate` and `DateTime ToDate` which spans hundreds of days.
Now, one sure way to filter the after-hours data is to compare the `UnixTimestamp` of each item to the regular trading time window 9:30 AM PST - 16:00 PM PST. That would require converting every `UnixTimestamp` to `DateTime`. This is a lot of comparison... Intuitively, it is better converting `FromDate` and `ToDate` to `UnixTimestamp` and filtering items out with Linq.

```cs
long unixTimeMsecToDate = new DateTimeOffset(aggrParams.ToDate).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
long unixTimeMsecFromDate = new DateTimeOffset(aggrParams.FromDate).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

However, I can't put my finger on exact code... Looping through the dates? How?

Comment: If you have `List<Aggregate` then you just use LINQ `Where` method to filter: `listAggregate.Where(a => unixTimeMsecFromDate <= a.UnixTimestamp && a.UnixTimestamp <= unixTimeMsecToDate)`. You can optionally do `ToList()` on the end to memoize filtering.

Comment: The problem is that Aggregate FromDate and ToDate are in DateTime format and I have multiple date that I have aggregated 1-min data for... So, unixTimeMsecFromDate and unixTimeMsecToDate needs to be somehow calculated for every date...

Comment: What does "Aggregate FromDate and ToDate" refer to? You have a range with from date and to date, which you can convert to Unix Timestamp format and then filter directly with `Where`. That is two conversions. Your `public class Aggregate` says `public decimal UnixTimestamp` => there is no `DateTime` in `Aggregate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get rid of Aggregate object and replace it by Quote object that come from a different library with time expressed as C# Date Time and resolve the problem in a straight way as follows, effectively filtering out After-hours data points:

```
        private void FilterExtendedTradingHours(List<Quote> quoteList, AggrParams aggrParams)
    {
        using (Log.VerboseCall())
        {
            if (aggrParams.Interval == "minute" || aggrParams.Interval == "hour")
            {
                Log.VerboseFormat("Initial {0} count: {1}", aggrParams.Interval, quoteList.Count);

                for(int i = quoteList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if ( quoteList[i].Date.TimeOfDay > new TimeSpan(16,  0,  0) || quoteList[i].Date.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0) )
                    {
                        quoteList.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }

                Log.VerboseFormat("Post-filtering {0} count: {1}", aggrParams.Interval, quoteList.Count);
            }
        }
    }
```